# jQuery Validate and go to page after successful submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working with `jquery.validate.min.js` script and its working fine as far as validation goes.

My problem is that its posting/submiting to data as it should but I need it to actually go to the `success.php` page after a successful submit.

Right now it just echos from `success.php` and shows in my main page.

How is the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#form1").validate({

    debug: false,
    rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    }
    },
    messages: {
    name: "Please enter your name.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.post('success.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    });

    }
});

}); 


<form id="form1" action="success.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</script>
```

How can I get it to go to the posting page after a successful submit?

Comment: You're using `ajax` in the `submitHandler` so that's the expected behavior.  Just remove your entire `submitHandler` callback function to revert to default form behavior including the redirect.  See my example below.

Comment: I got my answer in first, it contains a detailed explanation, a working demo, and it does not contain the unnecessary `SubmitIFValid` function and sloppy inline JavaScript `click` handler that's in the accepted answer.  Please kindly explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#form1").validate({

    debug: false,
    rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    }
    },
    messages: {
    name: "Please enter your name.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    }
});

}); 

function SubmitIfValid()
{
    if(!$("#form1").valid()) return false;  
    return true;
}

</script>

<form id="form1" action="success.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return SubmitIfValid();" />
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need `SubmitIfValid()`... that's what the plugin is doing already.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I took this code quickly from one of my examples which is slightly different, different enough to need a separate method for checking if it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code:**

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('success.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
}
```

> "Right now it just echos from `success.php` and shows in my main page."

Yes, that's exactly how [jQuery `$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is supposed to function.  It's `ajax`.

Simply remove the entire `submitHandler` callback function from `.validate()`.  There's really no point in using `ajax` to submit the form in this case if you just want it to redirect to the default page.  Remove the `submitHandler` option and it will behave like a standard form with a redirect based on your `action` attribute.

By default, the plugin will test the validity, and if the form is valid, it will submit like any other standard form and follow your `action="success.php"`.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/yCePj/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form1").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name.",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        }
    });

});
```